# Laravel Eloquent returning incorrect count numbers

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working with a laravel eloquent system and we are retrieving incorrect count numbers for our sql querying based off eloquent models.

The query on the database says 42 records but says total count is 13.

Here, you can see, we are doing:

```
$listings = $listings->paginate(100);
```

But the results only show 13 records

I performed this at the end:

```
file_put_contents("dumpquery.sql","202:".$listings->toSql());
file_put_contents("dump.sql","202:".print_r($listings->getBindings(),true));
```

and everything looks right.

```
    $listings = Listing::Select('listings.*')->leftJoin('listing_unlikes', function($join) use($user_id) {
                    $join->on('listing_unlikes.listing_id', '=', 'listings.id')
                        ->where('listing_unlikes.user_id', '=', $user_id);
                })->leftJoin('liked_listings', function($join) use($user_id) {
                    $join->on('liked_listings.listing_id', '=', 'listings.id')
                        ->where('liked_listings.user_id', '=', $user_id);
                });


    $listings = $listings->whereNull('listing_unlikes.listing_id');
    $listings = $listings->whereNull('liked_listings.listing_id');
    $listings = $listings->whereNotNull('bio')->where('bio','<>','');

    if($request->has('number_of_bedrooms')) {
        $request_bedrooms = intval($request->input('number_of_bedrooms'));

        $listings->where('number_of_bedrooms', '>=',  $request_bedrooms);
    }

    if($request->has('number_of_bathrooms')) {
        $requested_bathrooms = intval($request->input('number_of_bathrooms'));

        $listings->where('number_of_bathrooms', '>=', $requested_bathrooms);
    }

    if($request->has('price_start') && $request->has('price_end')) {
        $listings->where('price', '>=', $request->input('price_start'))
                ->where('price', '<=', $request->input('price_end'));
    }
    else {
        $listings->where('price', '>=', 5000);
    }

    //Sizing
    if($request->has('square_feet')) {
        $listings->where('square_feet', '>=', $request->input('square_feet'));
    }

    //Features
    if($request->has('type')) {
        $type = '%' . $request->input('type') . '%';
        $listings->where('type', 'LIKE', $type);
    }

    if($request->has('finish')) {
        $finish = '%' . $request->input('finish') . '%';
        $listings->where('finish', 'LIKE', $finish);
    }

    if($request->has('property_condition')) {
        $condition = '%' . $request->input('property_condition') . '%';
        $listings->where('property_condition', 'LIKE', $condition);
    }

    //Location Filters
    if($request->has('zip_code')) {
        $listings->where('zip_code', '=', $request->input('zip_code'));
    }

    if($request->has('town')) {
        $listings->where('town', '=', $request->input('town'));
    }

    if($request->has('county')) {
        $listings->where('county', '=', $request->input('county'));
    }

    if($request->has('city')) {
        $city = '%' . $request->input('city') . '%';
        $listings->where('city', 'LIKE', $city);
    }

    if($request->has('address')) {
        $address = '%' . $request->input('address') . '%';
        $listings->where('address', 'LIKE', $address);
    }

    $listings=$listings->whereNotNull('address');
    $listings=$listings->whereNotNull('zip_code');
    $listings=$listings->whereNotNull('city');
    $listings=$listings->whereNotNull('county');
    $listings=$listings->whereNotNull('town');

    // extra tables to include
    $listings->with('Agent')->has('Photos')->with('Photos')->with('ListingLikes');
    file_put_contents("dumpquery.sql","202:".$listings->toSql());
    file_put_contents("dump.sql","202:".print_r($listings->getBindings(),true));
    //$listings->with('Agent')->with('Photos')->with('ListingLikes');
    $listings = $listings->paginate(100);
    return $listings;
```

Here's the top of the var dump

```
object(Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator)#420 (9) {
  ["total":protected]=>
  int(13)
  ["lastPage":protected]=>
  int(1)
  ["items":protected]=>
 object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#707 (1) {
   ["items":protected]=>
    array(13) {
```

Here is the query produced:

```
select `listings`.* from `listings` left join `listing_unlikes` on 
`listing_unlikes`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`id` and 
`listing_unlikes`.`user_id` = 14 left join `liked_listings` on 
`liked_listings`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`id` and `liked_listings`.`user_id` 
= 14 where `listing_unlikes`.`listing_id` is null and 
`liked_listings`.`listing_id` is null and `bio` is not null and `bio` <> "" 
and `price` >= 5000 and `city` LIKE "%West Palm Beach%" and `address` is not 
null and `zip_code` is not null and `city` is not null and `county` is not 
null and `town` is not null and exists (select * from `listing_images` where 
   `listing_images`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`id`)
```

Comment: What does a var_dump of $listings show?

Comment: What is the logic to define `$listings`? There has to be a query associated with it. Maybe that is trimming some results?

Comment: @TimLewis see update

Comment: Can't do anything with "and everything looks right." Before you assign `$listings` to itself, how are you defining `$listings`? For example: `$listings = Listing::where(...)->with(...)-> ...` etc etc.

Comment: @TimLewis updated with code

Comment: @Adam heres the top of the var dump what do you need to see specifically

Comment: Your joins are likely creating multiple rows per listing.

Comment: @ceejayoz i added the resulting sql query how do i resolve this i really dont know much about laravel

Comment: @jkushner The easiest way to resolve this is to stop using joins, and start using Laravel's relationships. You're basically confusing Laravel's built-in magic here.

Comment: @ceejayoz unfortunately this needs to be completed today and i wont be able to integrate relationships into it without any experience in the given time span is 13 actually the correct count? can you assist in helping me with what i provided like i said im new to laravel.

Comment: I have no idea what the correct count is. Take a look at the data in your database and decide that for yourself.

Comment: @TimLewis any ideas? the count says 42 but its slicing to 13

Comment: @ceejayoz it should be 42 records but its returning 13. however the query generated shows 42.

Comment: If you replace the `paginate(100)` with `get()`, then do `dd(count($listings));` it should tell you how many records are being returned. That being said, how are you determining that the correct count should be 42? Are you running a query elsewhere?

Comment: @TimLewis im running it on phpmyadmin and it says 42 total. dd count says 13

Comment: So there's obviously a discrepancy between the query you're running on PhpMyAdmin vs the query being executed in Laravel. Are any of these records soft-deleted?

Comment: @TimLewis im running the query on phpmyadmin generated on laravel

Comment: @TimLewis `file_put_contents("dumpquery.sql","202:".$listings->toSql());`
    `file_put_contents("dump.sql","202:".print_r($listings->getBindings(),true));` thats what im using to generate the sql to run in phpmyadmin maybe theres something else going on thats filtering the query?

Comment: @TimLewis maybe this is not being shown in `toSql` ` maybe this - `$listings->with('Agent')->has('Photos')->with('Photos')->with('ListingLikes');` ?`

Comment: Yeah, `->toSql()` doesn't necessarily generate the entire query being used. I don't remember which cases will cause things to be excluded, but `->with()` shouldn't affect the result count, but `has()` definitely will. I dunno.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I was binding a integer as a string because db said varchar. Thanks